# How to change the name of the OIDC Client in pac4j

Tags: java, openid-connect, pac4j

I am experimenting with the pac4j in order to add OIDC to
a webapp. I started with the jee-pac4j-demo app.

From there I intend to go to a different OIDC Client.

- I was also able to switch the Client to another OAuth2.0-Client-ID inside the Google Cloud. (Just by setting different Credentials)
- I got the GoogleOidcClient working with a public hostname/ip. (Had to set the base_url of the context in some places).
- However, I am not able to change the *name* of the Client.

I changed

- the Name of the ID inside the Google Cloud Console
  from GoogleOidClient to Auth-Test
- and also client_name parameter in the callback URL accordingly

I got a malformed_url error from Google.

- then I also added `oidcClient.setName("Auth-Test")` to the factory.

Then I just get an "unauthorized".

Is GoogleOidcClient not supposed to be tampered with?

Is setName the wrong approach?

Is there a tutorial on how to add a "random" OIDC Client to the pac4j configuration?

Why does the logging still refer to localhost:8080?

```
JEE PAC4J DEMO 09:55:45.735 [http-nio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.p.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - url: http://localhost:8080/jee-pac4j-demo/oidc/index.jsp
JEE PAC4J DEMO 09:55:45.735 [http-nio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.p.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - clients: GoogleOidcClient | matchers: null
JEE PAC4J DEMO 09:55:45.735 [http-nio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.p.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - currentClients: []
JEE PAC4J DEMO 09:55:45.735 [http-nio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.p.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - Loaded profiles (from session: true): []
JEE PAC4J DEMO 09:55:45.735 [http-nio-8080-exec-52] DEBUG o.p.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic - unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the name of a client, `client.setName("xxx");` is the appropriate thing to do.

Sometimes, depending on the provider, there might be an issue with the fact that the client name is a request parameter. You can apply the client name on the path if need be: https://www.pac4j.org/5.7.x/docs/clients.html#3-the-callback-url

Comment: Now I am completely at a loss. I do set client.setName and also set the client_name in the Google Auth0 API Console as you suggested. And everything works if I use the client name "GoogleOidcClient" but not when using "MyAuthTest". In the latter case I do not even reach the Login Page of Google.

Comment: By the way, what is the rationale of setName() being part of the client object instead of the configuration object?

Comment: `setName()` is useful as you may have several SAML or OIDC clients for example. Do you see the new name ("MyAuthTest") in the logs?

Comment: My problem was that the name has also to be set inside the web.xml (not only in the DemoConfigFactory). Now it works, thank you!